# Prevent Google from indexing custom post types?

Tags: custom-post-types

I am using custom post types to add certain sections to my website. These post types are not meant to be treated like a blog, it's basically just an easy way for me to give the client access to managing certain sections, such as "reviews." Today I noticed that Google is indexing these custom post types and I was wondering how I can prevent that.

For instance, "reviews" is one of my custom post types and Google is indexing mywebsite.com/reviews as well as mywebsite.com/reviews/review, which looks terrible because there is no layout for it.

Is there any way to prevent Wordpress from even creating these sections? Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you write code for registering custom post-type try adding these attributes

```
public => false, has_archive => false, publicly_queryable => false, query_var => false
```

Otherwise, set these options to false in plugin that you might be using.

Comment: "publicaly_queryable" should be spelled "publicly_queryable" (no 'a' after 'public')

Answer (score 0):

Some functionality won't be working after using

```php
publickly_queryable => false, query_var => false
```

It's enough to stop indexing by the search engines by using only

```php
public => false, has_archive => false
```